# Has Lord Krishna ever reincarnated or appeared in his ethereal body in this phenomenal world?

Tags: krishna, avatars, rebirth

Since Krishna's death has he ever reincarnated or appeared in his ethereal body in this phenomenal world? Have there been any recorded sightings or visitations. I am not asking about other Vishnu avatars, I am asking specifically about Krishna.

Comment: You should be knowing how to write a good title by now. Please take care while you write questions and titles. Read [ask] and [How do I write a good title?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/10647/357396).

Comment: Mahavatar Babaji, the immortal yogi, is considered by many as manifestation of Lord Krishna. Many of the disciples call him by the name - Babaji Krishna!

Comment: @Chinmay Sarupria Ya Babiji is in the Atman in my heart, but Krishna is Krishna, blue, omniscient, omnipotent and omnipresent. Only by his Divine will  and Grace does he appear. Has he ever been seen since his samadi?

Comment: Many Yogis including Paramahansa Yogananda have said that they saw Lord Krishna face to face. As per Swami Sivananda, the more you progress spiritually, the more vision of Gods you get. Read this: https://www.ananda.org/autobiography/#chap43

Comment: @Chinmay Sarupria A fantastic book I will read it again and again. A lot of special friends in there. Nice to know that others have had visitations as well. Krishna brought Ganesha to see me. I wonder what they have planed for me.

Comment: You should also read Gospel of Sri Ramakrishna if you haven't already. http://www.ramakrishnavivekananda.info/gospel/gospel.htm The content is absolutely fantastic.

Answer (score 3):

From the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chaitanya_Mahaprabhu) on **Chaitanya Mahaprabhu**,

> The Gajapati king, Prataprudra Dev, regarded Chaitanya as Krishna's avatar
>
> Gaudiya Vaishnavas consider Chaitanya Mahaprabhu to be Lord Krishna himself, but appearing in covered form (channa avatar).

From [Śrī Caitanya-caritāmṛta » Ādi-līlā » Ādi 2: Śri Caitanya Mahāprabhu, the Supreme Personality of Godhead](https://www.vedabase.com/en/cc/adi/2),

> ‘nanda-suta’ bali’ yāṅre bhāgavate gāi
>
> sei kṛṣṇa avatīrṇa caitanya-gosāñi ~[CC Ādi 2.9](https://www.vedabase.com/en/cc/adi/2/9)
>
> He [Lord Kṛṣṇa] whom Śrīmad-Bhāgavatam describes as the son of Nanda Mahārāja has descended to earth as Lord Caitanya.

---

As mentioned in [this answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/28360/12304), **Shrinathji** also considered as an incarnation of Lord Krishna.

Comment: Ya all is God and Chaitanya Mahaprabhu sings and dances in my heart yes it is true. God  wears many clouds, you and me are but a few but has Krishna ever appeared again in his ethereal blue body in the world of phenomena. Or is he only to be seen by those who have eyes to see via his Grace ?

Comment: "is he only to be seen by those who have eyes to see via his Grace?" - yes, true... @FrankHestermann

Comment: Before the world was I am. Krishna is in the Celestial realm and the physical realm and also "within me". All is God.

Comment: "Gaudiya Vaishnavas consider Chaitanya Mahaprabhu to be Lord Krishna himself". This is very true and also completely ridiculous since they offer no proof of this.

Answer (score 3):

**Most likely Not**.

Lord Krishna got **liberated** at the end of his life, though he went through the Brahma-loka, the highest of heavenly planes first. While he was killed by a hunter named Jara, he was already in the state of Yoga.

> Coming up, Jara beheld a man dressed in yellow robes, **rapt in Yoga** and endued with many arms. ...  Narayana of fierce energy, the Creator and Destroyer of all, that preceptor of Yoga, filling Heaven with his splendour, **reached his own inconceivable region**. Krishna then met the deities and (celestial) Rishis and Charanas, O king, and the foremost ones among the Gandharvas and many beautiful Apsaras and Siddhas and Saddhyas. All of them, bending in humility, worshipped him.  [[source]](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m16/m16004.htm)

In above passage after the bolds, it feels like as of something happened after the liberation as well. IMO this could be due to verse translation ordering.

> BG 8.16 - All planes along with *BrahM-loka* are repetitive, O Arjuna. But reaching "Me", O son of Kunti, the rebirth doesn't happen.

---

Out of devotion, sometimes certain events are regarded as the 'reincarnation' of Krishna.

- [Srinathji](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shrinathji)

  > Shrinathji is a **form of Hindu god Krishna**, manifest as a seven-year-old child (Balak). ... Shrinathji is the central presiding deity of the Vaishnava sect known as the **Pushti Marg** (The way of grace) or the Vallabh Sampradaya or Shuddhadvaita, established by Vallabhacharya. Shrinathji is worshipped mainly by the followers of Bhakti Yoga and the Vaishnava in Gujarat and Rajasthan and Bhatia's and among others.

Comment: How can god get liberated, i think the scripture says "his own region" i.e vaikuntha, so basically home coming.

Comment: @Anisha, *Vaikuntha* is a name given to the ultimate state. Now if that is some region, then it's describable by whomsoever. However, the ultimate state (*param gati*) is not describable. Besides, I don't think Krishna left his mortal body with any desires in mind. A mind with mindful of desires would take a rebirth. But when a Yogi dies in the state of Yoga in a thoughtless state, wouldn't be reborn. A yogi like lord Krishna, who discussed about Moksha, if doesn't get Moksha himself, would be ironical. :-)

Comment: god cannot get moksha, he is karma phala data and moksha data thats why people killed by rama and krishna got moksha. He himself says that there is no work that affects me, only jivas whos works affect them which results in different states not god.

Comment: *"He himself says that there is no work that affects me"* -- @Anisha, Yes it's said like that. However, it has also to be interpreted exactly as translated (without direct/indirect tone). Which means, *"There is no Karma which affects '**Me**'"*. rather than, *"There is no Karma which affects '**Krishna**'"*. ---
 Note that, most of the translators put "Me" (which implies *Atma*) and not "me" (which implies Krishna).

Comment: i think you believe in more non dualistic interpretations, but you should read shankaracharya's commentary even he interprets them talking about god and not "jivaatmas", he ultimately believes that krishna-vishnu is nirguna. In geeta krishna says that all souls are his eternal fragmented parts you can't interpret it to mean atma(jiva-self), according to vedas we are part of parmatama, so that makes it clear what krishna is saying.

Comment: if you want more proof then read the commentary on a verse of geeta- this one https://www.holy-bhagavad-gita.org/chapter/4/verse/5 Shankaracharya writes that people who believe that krishna is normal human-yogi are "mudha","murkham"(idiots) who'll fall in hell for their blasphemous interpretations.